# Is there a way to JSON.parse without blocking the main thread?

Tags: javascript, performance, web-worker

Is there an async way to JSON.parse without blocking the main thread? I am receiving chunks of compressed JSON in an array that are really large, and currently it is blocking the main thread for ~5-6 seconds when it's time to parse it after decoding and decompressing (loading spinner is frozen).

I've tried web workers but the spinner is not continuous, so it freezes every half a second or so, which I assume is because it's needing to serialize and deserialize when sending the parsed data back to main thread which kind of defeats the purpose.

Any tips to approach this would be appreciated

Comment: Never used this, but maybe try https://github.com/ibmruntimes/yieldable-json

Comment: JSON Lines (jsonlines.org) is a commonly used format for streaming large json payloads incrementally. If you have control over the sender, you could break up the large JSON into reasonable chunks that can be parsed and stored incrementally.

Comment: @danh can I use this in react?

Comment: I've never tried, but I don't see why not, @user17443811